# Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init = System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, window, native

I have an app on Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 with Xamarin.Forms.
Now when I support UWP it runs fine WHEN I not are using Native tool chain.

Whwn I use Native tool chainI get this error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 'Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.'
```

When I call:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
```

And you can see, I trying to load all assmeblies I can when I readed this guide
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Target_Invocation_Exception_when_using_Compile_with_.NET_Native_tool_chain

And i have searched in 100 years how to solve it but havent success. The Microsoft Store do not allow to upload apps without Native tool chain...
I have updated to the latest Xamarin.Forms (2.4.0.282) and 
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (6.0.1).
Visual Studio 2017

Edited:
The callstack I found in the exception:

> **at
>   System.Reflection.Runtime.General.TypeResolver.TryResolveTypeReference(ReflectionDomain
>   reflectionDomain, MetadataReader reader, TypeReferenceHandle
>   typeReferenceHandle, Exception& exception) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Reflection.Core\src\System\Reflection\Runtime\General\TypeResolver.cs:line
>   209    at
>   System.Reflection.Runtime.General.TypeResolver.TryResolve(ReflectionDomain
>   reflectionDomain, MetadataReader reader, Handle typeDefRefOrSpec,
>   TypeContext typeContext, Exception& exception) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Reflection.Core\src\System\Reflection\Runtime\General\TypeResolver.cs:line
>   44    at
>   System.Reflection.Runtime.General.MetadataReaderExtensions.TryParseConstantValue(Handle
>   handle, ReflectionDomain reflectionDomain, MetadataReader reader,
>   Object& value) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Reflection.Core\src\System\Reflection\Runtime\General\MetadataReaderExtensions.cs:line
>   359    at
>   System.Reflection.Runtime.CustomAttributes.RuntimeNormalCustomAttributeData.ParseFixedArgument(MetadataReader
>   reader, FixedArgumentHandle fixedArgumentHandle, Boolean
>   throwIfMissingMetadata, Func'1 getTypeFromConstructor) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Reflection.Core\src\System\Reflection\Runtime\CustomAttributes\RuntimeNormalCustomAttributeData.cs:line
>   188    at
>   System.Reflection.Runtime.CustomAttributes.RuntimeNormalCustomAttributeData.GetConstructorArguments(Boolean
>   throwIfMissingMetadata) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Reflection.Core\src\System\Reflection\Runtime\CustomAttributes\RuntimeNormalCustomAttributeData.cs:line
>   67    at
>   System.Reflection.Runtime.CustomAttributes.RuntimeCustomAttributeData.get_ConstructorArguments()
>   in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Reflection.Core\src\System\Reflection\Runtime\CustomAttributes\RuntimeCustomAttributeData.cs:line
>   41    at
>   Internal.Reflection.Extensions.NonPortable.CustomAttributeInstantiator.Instantiate(CustomAttributeData
>   cad) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Reflection.Execution\src\Internal\Reflection\Extensions\NonPortable\CustomAttributeInstantiator.cs:line
>   34    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.Instantiate(IEnumerable'1
>   cads, Type actualElementType) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Reflection.Extensions\System\Reflection\CustomAttributeExtensions.cs:line
>   333    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly
>   element, Type attributeType) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\src\System.Reflection.Extensions\System\Reflection\CustomAttributeExtensions.cs:line
>   194    at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Type[]
>   attrTypes)    at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(IActivatedEventArgs
>   launchActivatedEventArgs, IEnumerable`1 rendererAssemblies)**

And I cant se any exe or dll that failed, the source variable is set to
 **unknown**

Edited 2:
Okey, Now I created a new UWP project with Xamarin.Forms and all my libraries included, and all my Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderers, I get same exceptopm, BUT when i comment out all:

```
//[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SmartBoxView), typeof(SmartBoxViewRenderer))]
```

Then it works on the test project, when I go back to my real project and comment out them i get another exception in the **Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init** method:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Cannot load assembly 'ClrCompression'. No metadata found for this assembly.'
```

Comment: For this exception please check [System.BadImageFormatException Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.BadImageFormatException/) to see if you met one of the scenario in the remarks. And try to find out which `dll` in your project lead this issue firstly.

Comment: Now I have updated the question, I can not see the dll or exe, i just see Unknown at source. But I shared the callstack if that is for some help?

Comment: Did you use an earlier version of a .NET Framework utility? Did you add  an unmanaged dll? Have tried change the  Platform target property? Could you please try  `Assembly.LoadFrom` method to see if one dll will throw this exception?

Comment: It has never works nice I used Visual Studio 2015 and older Xamarin.Forms, I have updated Xamarin, Visual Studio and so on all the time.

I have 2 unmanaged projects and they are included in the assemblies list.

Tried x64, x86

Assembly.LoadFrom is not supported in UWP, can I use Assembly.Load?

Comment: Okey, I created a new project and included all libraries then it works, but when I add a custom renderer for Xamarin.Forms, then I get the same exception. When I comment out this line:
//[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SmartBoxView), typeof(SmartBoxViewRenderer))]
Then is works... I can not use custom renderer

Comment: Updated the question again..